# How do I create a configuration schema of type array?

Tags: 9, configuration

I have a PHP array where an instance may look like this:

```
$mymodule_myarray = [
  'first' => 0,
];
```

I want to have it represented and initialised as part of the configuration for the custom module "mymodule":

I've after gettings some comments i now have the following in `mymodule.schema.yml`

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'My schema'
  mapping:
    mymodule_mystring:
      type: string
      label: 'Some string'
    mymodule_myarray:
      type: sequence
      label: 'Some array'
```

And I now have the following in `mymodule.settings.yml`:

```
mymodule_mystring: 'some string'
mymodule_myarray:
  'first'
  0
```

This produced the following error:

> Schema errors for mymodule.settings with the following errors: mymodule.settings:mymodule_nodetypes variable type is string but applied schema class is Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\Sequence

Creating a configuration for `mymodule_mystring` and initialising it works.

I guess I use the wrong syntax to create the schema for `mymodule_myarray`, but I unable to find documentation for how to do it right.

The only thing I can find (by looking at [the documentation at Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata#types) is that 'array' is not a supported type.

Please: How do I create a configuration schema of type array?

EDIT:

I am not concerned about translations. If creating an array is *not* the right way to go about this, is there an alternative approach?

Comment: You need to define a sequence, but this is usually not a simple array, instead you define a specific structure. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284769/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-store-arrays-of-information-with-configuration-ap. If the array has no structure then serialize the array to a string before storing it.

Comment: @4uk4 Thanks for linking to something that *may* be relevant. I've read the linked post, but I am probably too thick too understand it. My array has structure: A very simple one, a key (string) and a value (integer). The accepted answer shows a nested construct where type: `mapping` contains type `sequence`, which contains type `mapping`, with the relationship between this construct and some sort of array remains unexplained. It also does not discuss how to set default values for this in `settings.yml`.

Comment: Once you have a sequence you can set an array. But your `*.settings.yml` doesn't contain a valid array structure, there is no `=>` in YAML.

Comment: @4uk4 Tried your both suggestions. Now `.schema.yml` no longer gives errors, but `.settings.yml` is still nor right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for a structured array schema:

*/config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml*

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'My schema'
  mapping:
    mymodule_mystring:
      type: string
      label: 'Some string'
    mymodule_myarray:
      type: sequence
      label: 'My array'
      sequence:
        type: mapping
        label: 'My array item'
        mapping:
          label:
            type: label
            label: 'Some string'
          value:
            type: integer
            label: 'Some integer'
```

The YAML syntax to set this array as default setting:

*/config/install/mymodule.settings.yml*

```
mymodule_myarray:
  -
    label: first
    value: 0
  -
    label: second
    value: 1
```

BTW using type label for the string is intentionally so that you can translate "first", "second" and so on in different languages.

---

Edit:

It's hard to tell what the OP wants. The example did contain a translatable string, so I adjusted the schema accordingly. As already mentioned in the first comment, if you are not interested in defining the array as schema, then serialize it and store it in a string schema value.

If you want a simple array, to store untranslatable IDs, see this example from the core book module:

*/config/schema/book.schema.yml*

```
book.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'Book settings'
  mapping:
    allowed_types:
      type: sequence
      label: 'Content types allowed in book outlines'
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Content type'
```

*/config/install/book.settings.yml*

```
allowed_types:
  - book
```

This is probably the simplest example for storing an array in a configuration schema.

Answer (score 0):

I've upvoted and accepted the answer by 4uk4, since it answers my question as it was *originally* asked.

And I also agree with the recently added notion: "It's hard to tell what the OP wants." In this case, I didn't realize at the time I asked the question, that translations are a big part of this, and that I should have said up front that I was not into that.

But I've struggled with this problem over the last few days, and have started to realize that creating an array type configuration is not always the right thing to do, because it carries too much baggage.

So, I've found an alternative solution, and I am going to post it below, in case somebody else is struggling with the same thing, and is looking for a *simple* solution. My solution:

1. Create the schema for the array by setting its type to `ignore`.
2. Do *not* use `.settings.yml` to set the initial (default) value. Instead, do it by PHP elsewhere (in my case in the `setUp()` function of a PHPUNit Kernel test class):

So I ended up with:

**mymodule.schema.yml:**

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'My schema'
  mapping:
    mymodule_mystring:
      type: string
      label: 'Some string'
    mymodule_myarray:
      type: ignore
      label: 'Some array'
```

**mymodule.settings.yml:**

```
mymodule_mystring: 'some string'
```

And then use the following PHP to initialise:

```
$this->setMymoduleSettings([
  'mymodule_myarray' => [
    'first' => 0,
  ],
]);
```